# oracle sql start range end range with count

Tags: sql, oracle, range

This is the table I query over:

```
lcn_code   start_num      end_num
company1         1          1
company1         3          3
company1         5          5
company1         6          6
company1         7          7
company2         2          2
company2         4          4
company2         9          9
company2         8          8
```

As you can see, the top row start_num to end_num is 1 & 1 so it is a count of 1,  but then theres a sequence break under company1, and the next number they have is 3.  So I dont want '2' reported under company1.  That bit I can do (just).

The bit I'm having trouble with is below:
Between the 3rd and 5th row there is no seqence breaks.. 5,6,7 so I'd like to see a start and end range being 5 > 7 with a count of 3, not as seperate rows like in the table.

I've tried different variations min(start_num), max(end_num) but it gives me all the whole range company1 = 1 - 7.

I need it to look like this....

```
lcn_code    start      end     count
company1       1        1        1 
company1       3        3        1
company1       5        7        3

company2       2        2        1
company2       4        4        1
company2       8        9        2
```

etc etc...

Basically give me a total count of that range when there no sequense breaks, rather than individual rows.

Very novice at this so i'd need the whole string please.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is a way for you to access the following/previous rows from the current one in your query, I dont remember the syntax though. You would need to look it up then doing this would be much easier

Comment: Another way, you could do a PL/SQL block and keep track of the last row range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's little bit complicated, hopefully you will manage to simplify that...

```
select lcn_code, min(start_num), max(end_num), count(*)
  from (
        select a.*,
               max(bound_break) over(partition by lcn_code
                                         order by end_num
                                     ) rank_num
          from (select a.*, 
                       case 
                       when end_num = prev_num + 1 and
                            end_num = next_num - 1 
                         then null 
                       when end_num = prev_num + 1  
                         then null
                       when end_num = next_num - 1 
                         then end_num
                         else end_num 
                       end as bound_break                             
                from (select a.*, 
                             lag(start_num, 1, null) over(partition by lcn_code order by end_num) as prev_num,
                             lead(start_num, 1, null) over(partition by lcn_code order by end_num) as next_num 
                        from test_data a
                     ) a
               ) a 
        )
group by lcn_code, rank_num
order by lcn_code, rank_num
;
```

Comment: wow thank you for that it worked perfectly, no wonder i didnt get it right myself.  the only other thing i now need to join another file to get another field but im not sure where abouts to add the joining file in that script above?

Comment: actually i've just worked it out!  thank you very much for youe help!

Comment: No problem. Please rank up my answer if it works :-)